# PhpStorm too slow after npm install

Tags: php, laravel, npm, phpstorm, npm-install

Sorry to say that English is my second language.

I have created a new Laravel project and then `composer install` and `npm install` in iterm.

Then I want to open the project via PhpStorm but the IDE was too slow to open it. Time indexing the files was more than 1 hour!

I tried to increase the memory limit from 768mb to 2048mb but it has the same behavior. And added the `node_modules` directory to the `.gitignore` file but the same behavior.

The following is the `phpstorm.voptions` file:

[image]

My OS is OSX 10.11.5, the java version is 1.8.0_91 64bit, PhpStorm version is 2016.1.2.

What can I do to solve it?

Comment: Add `node_modules` to the `Excluded` in Settings -> Directories.

Comment: I marked the node_modules as `Excluded`,but it doesn't work

Comment: What "does not work" means? It surely works for me for ages.

Comment: I'm so sorry ,I works when I reopen the project again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to marking any node_modules folders as Excluded, I found the real trick was adding node_modules/ to your .gitignore

The IDE might stop indexing, but it seems like the git is still scanning for non indexed files? It has been really bad lately, but as soon as I added node_modules/ to my .gitignore, the IDE immediately got way snappier.